# Parse table data from website using Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, xpath

I am unable to figure out how to properly obtain data from html table data. So far I have only been able to get the class, but not the data within the td class. I am using the [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna) library to Parse the html.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
    if let doc = Kanna.HTML(url: (NSURL(string: "your url here")!), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        for link in doc.xpath("//td/@class"){
            print(link.text!)
            //mealType.append(link.text!)
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<td class="views-field views-field-field-test">TEST!</td>
```

The class is returned, but how do I get the data inside of the class? (I want the "*TEST!*")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should return the `td` element instead of its `class` attribute, because the target value is the text 'inside' the `td` element, not 'inside' of the class.

That can be done by changing your XPath to be as follow :

```
//td[@class]
```

The above XPath means *get all `td` element that has `class` attribute*. If you need to be specific on the `class` attribute value of the target `td` element, that can be done this way :

```
//td[@class='views-field views-field-field-test']
```

<sub>caveat: I don't do iOS development and so didn't know Kanna, except by skimming through its github readme page.</sub>